# Loop through JSON - special way

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, recursion

I got a really big nested **JSON object** like this one:

```js
let myData = {
  character: {
    player: {
      player_1: { type: "player1", test:"A" },
      player_2: { type: "player2", test:"B" },
      player_3: { type: "player3", test:"C" }
    },
    enemy: {
      enemy_walk: {
        enemy_walk_1: { type:"enemy_walkA", test: "..." },
        enemy_walk_2: { type:"enemy_walkB", test: "..." },
        enemy_walk_3: { type:"enemy_walkY", test: "..." }
      }
    }
  },
  blocks: {
    wall: {
      wall_1: { type:"wallA", test: "..." },
      wall_2: { type:"wallB", test: "..." },
    },
    obstacle: {
      brick: {
        brick1: { type:"brickA", test: "..." },
        brick2: { type:"brickC", test: "..." },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

... and I'd like to loop through every subtree to get a list like this (where the last object of every subtree gets a brand new property called `src` that represents the **path of the object as string**:

```
let result = {
  character: {
    player: {
      player_1: { type: "player1", test:"A", src: "character/player/player_1" },
      player_2: { type: "player2", test:"B", src: "character/player/player_2" },
      player_3: { type: "player3", test:"C", src: "character/player/player_3" }
    },
    enemy: {
      enemy_walk: {
        enemy_walk_1: { type:"enemy_walkA", test: "...", src: "character/enemy/enemy_walk_1" },
        enemy_walk_2: { type:"enemy_walkB", test: "...", src: "character/enemy/enemy_walk_2" },
        enemy_walk_3: { type:"enemy_walkY", test: "...", src: "character/enemy/enemy_walk_3" }
      }
    }
  },
  blocks: {
    wall: {
      wall_1: { type:"wallA", test: "...", src: "blocks/wall/wall_1" },
      wall_2: { type:"wallB", test: "...", src: "blocks/wall/wall_2" },
    },
    obstacle: {
      brick: {
        brick1: { type:"brickA", test: "...", src: "blocks/obstacle/brick/brick1" },
        brick2: { type:"brickC", test: "...", src: "blocks/obstacle/brick/brick2" },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Because I do not really got a clue how to start this code is all that I've got so far.

```js
var myData={character:{player:{player_1:{type:"player1",test:"A"},player_2:{type:"player2",test:"B"},player_3:{type:"player3",test:"C"}},enemy:{enemy_walk:{enemy_walk_1:{type:"enemy_walkA",test:"..."},enemy_walk_2:{type:"enemy_walkB",test:"..."},enemy_walk_3:{type:"enemy_walkY",test:"..."}}}},blocks:{wall:{wall_1:{type:"wallA",test:"..."},wall_2:{type:"wallB",test:"..."}},obstacle:{brick:{brick1:{type:"brickA",test:"..."},brick2:{type:"brickC",test:"..."}}}}};

let updateSRC = function(data) {
  let _data = data;
  let recursive = function(_data) {
    for (let key in _data) {
      if (typeof _data[key] == "Object") {
        recursive(_data[key]);
      } else {
         _data[key].src = "?"
      }
    }; recursive(_data)
  }; return _data || null;
}
let result = updateSRC(myData);
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: do you want to get a new object or an updated object?

Comment: @NinaScholz:  principle, this makes little difference as long as all attributes are adopted and the object has the same structure. In the end, both will be almost identical only the "new" or "updated" object will get one property per branch more.

Comment: @NinaScholz: Or is your question aimed at a specific problem? What do you think is the better option?

Comment: There's no such thing as a *JSON Object* – JSON is *always* a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just make a recursive function with a flag (here `leaf`) to indicate whether the you have any more nested objects.

You can keep track of where you are using a parameter to the function(`path`). With each recursive step, just add the key to the path.

This will alter the object in place, but it shouldn't be hard to create a new object using the same technique if that's what you're after.

```js
let myData = {character: {player: {player_1: { type: "player1", test:"A" },player_2: { type: "player2", test:"B" },player_3: { type: "player3", test:"C" }},enemy: {enemy_walk: {enemy_walk_1: { type:"enemy_walkA", test: "..." },enemy_walk_2: { type:"enemy_walkB", test: "..." },enemy_walk_3: { type:"enemy_walkY", test: "..." }}}},blocks: {wall: {wall_1: { type:"wallA", test: "..." },wall_2: { type:"wallB", test: "..." },},obstacle: {brick: {brick1: { type:"brickA", test: "..." },brick2: { type:"brickC", test: "..." },}}}}

function walk(obj, path=''){
    let leaf = true
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' ){
            walk(obj[key], path +  '/' + key)
            leaf = false // this object has children, so don't add `src` prop
        }
    })
    if (leaf) obj['src'] = path
}

walk(myData)
console.log(myData)
```

Comment: This looks like a functioning and clever implementation. Thanks for your help. (`+1`)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new object and store the path as `src` if no further nested object is found.

```js
function getUpdate(object, path = []) {
    return Object.assign(...Object
        .entries(object)
        .map(([k, v]) => v && typeof v === 'object'
            ? { [k]: getUpdate(v, path.concat(k)) }
            : { [k]: v, src: path.join('/') }
        )
    );
}

var object = { character: { player: { player_1: { type: "player1", test: "A" }, player_2: { type: "player2", test: "B" }, player_3: { type: "player3", test: "C" } }, enemy: { enemy_walk: { enemy_walk_1: { type: "enemy_walkA", test: "..." }, enemy_walk_2: { type: "enemy_walkB", test: "..." }, enemy_walk_3: { type: "enemy_walkY", test: "..." } } } }, blocks: { wall: { wall_1: { type: "wallA", test: "..." }, wall_2: { type: "wallB", test: "..." } }, obstacle: { brick: { brick1: { type: "brickA", test: "..." }, brick2: { type: "brickC", test: "..." } } } } };

console.log(getUpdate(object));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Wow. I'm really surprised. Thanks for your help. To be honest I haven't heard anything about Object.assign yet. I will have a look at the docs. (`+1`)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a common property like `type` in all leaves can check for that property

```js
const setPaths = (o, path = '') => {
  Object.keys(o).forEach(k => {
    const currPath = path ? `${path}/${k}` : k;
    if ('type' in o[k]) {
       o[k].src = currPath;
    } else {     
      setPaths(o[k], currPath)
    }
  })
}
setPaths(myData)

console.log(myData)
```

```html
<script>
  let myData = {
    character: {
      player: {
        player_1: {
          type: "player1",
          test: "A"
        },
        player_2: {
          type: "player2",
          test: "B"
        },
        player_3: {
          type: "player3",
          test: "C"
        }
      },
      enemy: {
        enemy_walk: {
          enemy_walk_1: {
            type: "enemy_walkA",
            test: "..."
          },
          enemy_walk_2: {
            type: "enemy_walkB",
            test: "..."
          },
          enemy_walk_3: {
            type: "enemy_walkY",
            test: "..."
          }
        }
      }
    },
    blocks: {
      wall: {
        wall_1: {
          type: "wallA",
          test: "..."
        },
        wall_2: {
          type: "wallB",
          test: "..."
        },
      },
      obstacle: {
        brick: {
          brick1: {
            type: "brickA",
            test: "..."
          },
          brick2: {
            type: "brickC",
            test: "..."
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Wow. Also this is a good idea that actually works. To be honest, that was my first approach to this property and you did it well. Thank you very much. (`+1`)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure functional implementation. It does not modify the input and instead returns a new object with `path` set on all objects that have a `type` field.

```
const addPath = (o = {}, path = []) =>
  // non-object? return input
  Object (o) !== o
    ? o

  // object has 'type'? assign 'path'
  : o.type !== undefined
    ? { ...o, path: [...path, o.type] .join ('/') }

  // otherwise: recur on each value with updated path
  : Object
      .entries (o)
      .reduce
        ( (acc, [key, value]) =>
            ({ ...acc, [key]: addPath (value, [...path, key]) })
        , {}
        )
```

Verify the result in your browser below

```js
const addPath = (o = {}, path = []) =>
  Object (o) !== o
    ? o
  : o.type !== undefined
    ? { ...o, path: [...path, o.type] .join ('/') }
  : Object
      .entries (o)
      .reduce
        ( (acc, [key, value]) =>
            ({ ...acc, [key]: addPath (value, [...path, key]) })
        , {}
        )
        
let myData = {
  character: {
    player: {
      player_1: { type: "player1", test:"A" },
      player_2: { type: "player2", test:"B" },
      player_3: { type: "player3", test:"C" }
    },
    enemy: {
      enemy_walk: {
        enemy_walk_1: { type:"enemy_walkA", test: "..." },
        enemy_walk_2: { type:"enemy_walkB", test: "..." },
        enemy_walk_3: { type:"enemy_walkY", test: "..." }
      }
    }
  },
  blocks: {
    wall: {
      wall_1: { type:"wallA", test: "..." },
      wall_2: { type:"wallB", test: "..." },
    },
    obstacle: {
      brick: {
        brick1: { type:"brickA", test: "..." },
        brick2: { type:"brickC", test: "..." },
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log (addPath (myData))
```

Output

```
{
  "character": {
    "player": {
      "player_1": {
        "type": "player1",
        "test": "A",
        "path": "character/player/player_1/player1"
      },
      "player_2": {
        "type": "player2",
        "test": "B",
        "path": "character/player/player_2/player2"
      },
      "player_3": {
        "type": "player3",
        "test": "C",
        "path": "character/player/player_3/player3"
      }
    },
    "enemy": {
      "enemy_walk": {
        "enemy_walk_1": {
          "type": "enemy_walkA",
          "test": "...",
          "path": "character/enemy/enemy_walk/enemy_walk_1/enemy_walkA"
        },
        "enemy_walk_2": {
          "type": "enemy_walkB",
          "test": "...",
          "path": "character/enemy/enemy_walk/enemy_walk_2/enemy_walkB"
        },
        "enemy_walk_3": {
          "type": "enemy_walkY",
          "test": "...",
          "path": "character/enemy/enemy_walk/enemy_walk_3/enemy_walkY"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "blocks": {
    "wall": {
      "wall_1": {
        "type": "wallA",
        "test": "...",
        "path": "blocks/wall/wall_1/wallA"
      },
      "wall_2": {
        "type": "wallB",
        "test": "...",
        "path": "blocks/wall/wall_2/wallB"
      }
    },
    "obstacle": {
      "brick": {
        "brick1": {
          "type": "brickA",
          "test": "...",
          "path": "blocks/obstacle/brick/brick1/brickA"
        },
        "brick2": {
          "type": "brickC",
          "test": "...",
          "path": "blocks/obstacle/brick/brick2/brickC"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```